# how to deinterleave image channel in SSE

Tags: image-processing, sse, simd, sse2

is there any way we can DE-interleave 32bpp image channels similar as below code in neon.

```
//Read all r,g,b,a pixels into 4 registers
uint8x8x4_t SrcPixels8x8x4= vld4_u8(inPixel32);

ChannelR1_32x4 = vmovl_u16(vget_low_u16(vmovl_u8(SrcPixels8x8x4.val[0]))), 
channelR2_32x4 = vmovl_u16(vget_high_u16(vmovl_u8(SrcPixels8x8x4.val[0]))), vGaussElement_32x4_high);
```

basically i want all color channels in separate vectors with every vector has 4 elements of 32bits to do some calculation but i am not very familiar with SSE and could not find such instruction in SSE or if some one can provide better ways to do that? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are your pixels 4 x 8 bits RGBA, i.e. 32 bits for each pixel ? And what output format do you want, separate vectors of 8 bit R, G, B, and A, or do you also want to unpack the 8 bit values to 32 bits at the same time ?

Comment: yeah my image is 32 bpp 8 bits per pixel and yeas I also want to unpack the 8 bit values to 32 bits at the same time. something like R, R, R, R( where each R takes 32 bits ), simillarily B, B, B,B... basically this helps when i multiply each R, B,G, A by some 32 bit value.

Comment: I am just trying to implement Gaussian blur where my Gaussian coefficient are of 32 bit so i need this de interleaving and then i can simply multiply de-Interleaved vectors with gauss vector

Comment: You probably don't want to do 32x32 bit multiplies for a filter such as this, especially if it's performance-critical. Use fixed point 16x16 multiplies.

Comment: can you please show how can we do 16x16 and store result in 32 bit.. yeah actully my gausss coefficient are 16 bit values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 8 bit values are unsigned you can just do this with shifting and masking, much like you would for scalar code, e.g.

```c
__m128i vrgba;

__m128i vr = _mm_and_si128(vrgba, _mm_set1_epi32(0xff));
__m128i vg = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi32(vrgba, 8), _mm_set1_epi32(0xff));
__m128i vb = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi32(vrgba, 16), _mm_set1_epi32(0xff));
__m128i va = _mm_srli_epi32(vrgba, 24);
```

Note that I'm assuming your RGBA elements have the R component in the LS 8 bits and the A component in the MS 8 bits, but if they are the opposite endianness you can just change the names of the `vr`/`vg`/`vb`/`va` vectors.

Comment: Thanks paul that worked i am wondering how can we modify this to have 16 bits packing rather than 32

Comment: You can do something very similar for 16 bits - obviously you would need to start with two input vectors though. If you need further help with this then post a new question asking for a 16 bit solution and tag it `simd` and I'll come up with something (unless someone else beats me to it).

Comment: Sure i was able to do this for 32 bit. i will see performance factors first and if need i will add another question with actual algorithm i am trying to implement. Thanku so much for you kind help i was stuck with this from 2 days since its very hard to find good docmentation about it